# update particular option in section in ".ini" file using ConfigParser

Tags: python, python-3.x, configparser

I am trying to update a particular option in my `config.ini` file using `ConfigParser`.

This is my `config.ini` file:

```
[remote-server-details]                                                                                                 

MACHINE_NAME =                                                                                                   

MACHINE_USERNAME =                                                                                               

MACHINE_PASSWORD = Welcome!23
```

And this is my step file in Python:

```
@step('I change the following config options in section "{section_name}" in the {config_file_type} config file')
def set_dag_config_section_values(context, section_name, config_file_type):
    parameters = ast.literal_eval(context.text)
    context.conf[config_file_type].read(context.dag_config_file[config_file_type])
    context.conf[config_file_type].remove_section(section_name)
    context.conf[config_file_type].add_section(section_name)
    for option, value in parameters.iteritems():
        context.conf[config_file_type].set(section_name, option, value)

    with open(context.dag_config_file[config_file_type], 'w+') as configfile:
        context.conf[config_file_type].write(configfile)

    context.conf[config_file_type].read(context.dag_config_file[config_file_type])
    readin_parameters = dict(context.conf[config_file_type].items(section_name))
    sort_dict(parameters)
    sort_dict(readin_parameters)
    assert readin_parameters == parameters, 'Value could not be set. %s does not match config contents %s' % (parameters, readin_parameters)
```

I need to update only `MACHINE_NAME` and `MACHINE_USERNAME`, as `MACHINE_PASSWORD` is already contained in the config file, but I'm getting this error:

```
 INFO - Subtask:     remote_server_details['MACHINE_PASSWORD'],
      [2018-08-17 17:40:04,723] {{base_task_runner.py:98}} INFO - Subtask: KeyError: 'MACHINE_PASSWORD'
```

Comment: Where in your code do you make a distinction between `MACHINE_NAME`/`MACHINE_USERNAME`, and `MACHINE_PASSWORD`? I think you also need to show us how you call that function. Also, if you have more detailed error messages than the two lines you've shown, that would be helpful.

Comment: Ah, I think I understand: You want to write options to the file based on whether they are already contained or not (instead of directly based on their name).

Comment: @mkrieger1:ahh yes,you got the point ,password is already present in the config file ,i just need to update the machine name and user name